# Remove nodes from graph or reset entire default graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

When working with the default global graph, is it possible to remove nodes after they've been added, or alternatively to reset the default graph to empty? When working with TF interactively in IPython, I find myself having to restart the kernel repeatedly. I would like to be able to experiment with graphs more easily if possible.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**Update 11/2/2016**

`tf.reset_default_graph()`

**Old stuff**

There's `reset_default_graph`, but not part of public API (I think it should be, does someone wants to [file an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) on GitHub?)

My work-around to reset things is this:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
```

Comment: Why is `sess = tf.InteractiveSession()` is needed?

Answer (score 36):

By default, a session is constructed around the default graph.
To avoid leaving dead nodes in the session, you need to either control the default graph or use an explicit graph.

- To clear the default graph, you can use the [tf.reset_default_graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#reset_default_graph) function.

  ```
  tf.reset_default_graph()
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  ```
- You can also construct explicitly a graph and avoid using the default one. If you use a normal `Session`, you will need to fully create the graph before constructing the session. For `InteractiveSession`, you can just declare the graph and use it as a context to declare further changes:

  ```
  g = tf.Graph()
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=g)
  with g.asdefault():
      # Put variable declaration and other tf operation
      # in the graph context
      ....
      b = tf.matmul(A, x)
      ....

   sess.run([b], ...)
  ```

EDIT: For recent versions of `tensorflow` (1.0+), the correct function is [`g.as_default`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#as_default).

Comment: In tensorflow >= 1.0, it is `g.as_default()`

Comment: Spelling: In the with statement you forgot the underscore in g.as_default()

Comment: Why is `sess = tf.InteractiveSession()` is needed?

Answer (score 5):

IPython / Jupyter notebook cells keep state between runs of a cell.

Create a custom graph:

```
def main():
    # Define your model
    data = tf.placeholder(...)
    model = ...

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    main()
```

Once ran, the graph is cleaned up.

Comment: "Once ran, the graph is cleaned up" I don't think that this is true.

Answer (score 5):

**Tensorflow 2.0 Compatible Answer**: In **`Tensorflow Version >= 2.0`**, the Command to Reset Entire Default Graph, when run in Graph Mode is **`tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph`**.

**NOTE**: The default graph is a property of the current thread. This function applies only to the current thread. Calling this function while a **`tf.compat.v1.Session`** or **`tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession`** is active will result in undefined behavior. Using any previously created **`tf.Operation`** or **`tf.Tensor`** objects after calling this function will result in undefined behavior.

***Raises***: ***AssertionError: If this function is called within a nested graph.***

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I faced the very same problem, but

```py
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

at the beginning of the cell in which the model (Keras, in my case) was constructed and trained helped to "cut the clutter" so only the current graph remains in the TensorBoard visualization after repeated runs of the same cell.

Environment: TensorFlow 2.0 (`tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0b1`) in Colab with built-in TensorBoard (using the `%load_ext tensorboard` trick).