# tensorflow Adamoptimizer beta1_power not initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm doing transfer learning, thus I pre-trained a network, saved the variables (w, b) in a file; closed the program; re-opened another program; restored all old variables; defined some new layers of variables, initialized them; then started re-training. SGD optimizer works in my code, but if I change the optimizer to Adam, it gives me the following error:

`2017-08-03 21:28:08.785092: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value beta1_power`

My code:

```
# Session Start
sess = tf.Session()
# restore pre-trained parameters
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, "./pre_train/step1.ckpt")
# init new parameters
weights2 = {
    'fnn_w1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_1], stddev= sd), name='fnn_w1'),
    'fnn_w2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, 1], stddev= sd), name='fnn_w2')
}
biases2 = {
    'fnn_b1': tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_hidden_1]), name='fnn_b1'),
    'fnn_b2': tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]), name='fnn_b2')
}
parameters2 = {**weights2, **biases2}
init_params2 = tf.variables_initializer(parameters2.values())
sess.run(init_params2)

# Construct model
encoder_op = encoder(X)
focusFnn_op = focusFnn(encoder_op)  # for one gene a time prediction
decoder_op = decoder(encoder_op)  # for pearson correlation of the whole matrix #bug (8092, 0)

# Prediction and truth
y_pred = focusFnn_op  # [m, 1]
y_true = X[:, j]
y_benchmark = M[:, j]  # benchmark for cost_fnn
M_train = df2_train.values[:, j:j+1]  # benchmark for corr
M_valid = df2_valid.values[:, j:j+1]

# Define loss and optimizer, minimize the squared error
with tf.name_scope("Metrics"):
    cost_fnn = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y_true - y_pred, 2))
    cost_fnn_benchmark = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y_pred- y_benchmark, 2))
    cost_decoder = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(X - decoder_op, 2))
    cost_decoder_benchmark = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(decoder_op - M, 2))
    tf.summary.scalar('cost_fnn', cost_fnn)
    tf.summary.scalar('cost_fnn_benchmark', cost_fnn_benchmark)
    tf.summary.scalar('cost_decoder', cost_decoder)
    tf.summary.scalar('cost_decoder_benchmark', cost_decoder_benchmark)

# optimizer = (
#     tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).
#     minimize(cost_fnn, var_list=[list(weights2.values()), list(biases2.values())])
# )# frozen other variables

optimizer = (
    tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).
    minimize(cost_fnn)
)# frozen other variables
print("# Updated layers: ", "fnn layers\n")

train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir+'/train', sess.graph)
valid_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir+'/valid', sess.graph)
# benchmark_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir+'/benchmark', sess.graph)

# Evaluate the init network
[cost_train, h_train] = sess.run([cost_fnn, y_pred], feed_dict={X: df_train.values})
[cost_valid, h_valid] = sess.run([cost_fnn, y_pred], feed_dict={X: df_valid.values})
```

Answer (score 1):

The beta-variables are variables used by the AdamOptimizer that need to be initialized similarily to your other variables. You can either initialize them with the tf.global_variables_initializer() after creating the optimizer, or look up the variables and initialize them directly with tf.variables_initializer().

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem is that I have to keep weights restored from pre-training frozen, and `tf.global_variables_initializer()` re-init those variables with random values. Is there some way to init beta-variables only and not other weights? I can't find the correct names for beta-variables.

Comment: You should be able to pass tf.variables to the AdamOptimizer with the beta1 and beta2 keywords, then you can initialize them directly

Comment: `sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, "./pre_train/step1.ckpt")
init_all = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_all)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost, var_list=[list(focusFnn_params.values())])`

Even with this gloabal init, I got the following error:
`FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value beta2_power
  [[Node: beta2_power/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@focusFnn_w1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](beta2_power)]]`

Comment: You gotta run the init after creating the optimizer. However, as you mentioned, this will reset the other variables. You can try: ```beta1 = tf.Variable(0.9) beta2=tf.Variable(0.999) optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate, beta1=beta1, beta2=beta2).... sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([beta1, beta2])```

Comment: Thanks! Like you said, running init after creating the optimizer makes the optimizer work. However, after setting beta1 and beta2, it gives the old error message: `FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value beta1_power
  [[Node: beta1_power/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@encoder_w1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](beta1_power)]]`

Comment: my new code: 
`beta1 = tf.Variable(0.9)
beta2=tf.Variable(0.999)
# train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost, var_list=[list(focusFnn_params.values())])
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate, beta1=beta1, beta2=beta2).minimize(cost)
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([beta1, beta2]))`

Comment: Can you try to give the beta1 variable a name to see if that name is reflected in the errormsg? Edit: Also try giving a name to the optimizer itself

Comment: You can see the variables being created in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py. A rather hacky solution would be to run sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([optimizer.beta1_power, optimizer.beta2_power])

Comment: Thanks! But, `beta1 = tf.Variable(0.9)
beta2=tf.Variable(0.999)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate, beta1=beta1, beta2=beta2)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([optimizer.beta1_power, optimizer.beta2_power]))` gives a new error: `sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([optimizer.beta1_power, optimizer.beta2_power]))
AttributeError: 'AdamOptimizer' object has no attribute 'beta1_power'`

Comment: Hmm. An even more hacky way would be to search for a variable with the name 'beta1_power' (and probably 'beta2_power') in tf.global_variables() and initialize these. This seems like detour though

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by following operation:

```
     train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)
     # Initialize the variables and reload weights
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     net.load_initial_weights(sess)
```

It seems worked.First I initialized the global variables,and I load the pre-trained weights.**Attention**,you must define your AdamOptimizer previously and then run the `tf.global_variables_initializer()` otherwise the `beta variable` would still not be initialized

My senior taught me just now.Thank him vert much

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you got anywhere with this after our comment exchange, but I just encountered the same problem and solved it by running:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    sess.run(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('beta1_power/Assign:0'))
    sess.run(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('beta2_power/Assign:0'))
    ...
```

Comment: thanks! I found another way that works, and haven't tried this solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by saving all variables, rather than only weights and biases in step1. In step2, define train_op first, then saver.restore()

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

before the graph construction.

However, you still have to make sure the *solver* declaration is done before the creation of the Saver:

```
solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
...
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

Reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765336/remove-nodes-from-graph-or-reset-entire-default-graph
https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/basics/weights_loading_scope.py

Answer (score 0):

The Adam optimizer's variables must be initialized before used.
To initialize the Adam optimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(optimizer.variables()))
```