# Switching in tensorflow between python & jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to work in tensorflow in both python (via PyCharm) to train the model, and Jupyter notebook to analyze the results.

However, after I restore a session checkpoint & analyze the data in jupyer, I cant retrain a model at the same time due to the " Blas GEMM launch failed" error. I know this issue can be resolved by restarting the jupyter kernel (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765336/remove-nodes-from-graph-or-reset-entire-default-graph)), however I would prefer not having to do that. Is there any way of switching back and forth between the two without have to restart the ipython kernel?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not exactly clear, how you use PyCharm and Jupyter at the same time. Do you connect to the same Jupyter server in PyCharm? If that is the case, there should be no problems in connecting to the server via a browser and PyCharm at the same time.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, I launch jupyter directly from Anaconda. As far as I know, it is completely independent from Pycharm. Is there a way to do it differently?

Comment: I mean, you can launch a Jupyter server whatever way you want and connect to it via PyCharm and any web browser. PyCharm has a Jupyter notebook interface.

Comment: @EliKorvigo thnx! Do you know how to connect it to with pycharm?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html