# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float and shape [?,10]

Tags: tensorflow, placeholder, shapes

I don't know why occur this problem,I have checked many times, I have feed `xs` and `ys` to `feed_dict`. So, what is the reason for this problem? How do I modify my code to solve these error? Below is the error log.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float and shape [?,10]
[[node Placeholder_2 (defined at /home/jiayu/dropout.py:41)  = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,10], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
[[{{node Mean_5/_55}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_271_Mean_5", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

This code run on `ubuntu 16.04`, `tensorflow 1.12.0` and `python 3.6.8`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

# load data
digits = load_digits()
X = digits.data
y = digits.target
y = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.3)

def add_layer(inputs, in_size, out_size, layer_name, activation_function=None, ):
    # add one more layer and return the output of this layer
    Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size, out_size]))
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, out_size]) + 0.1, )
    Wx_plus_b = tf.matmul(inputs, Weights) + biases
    # here to dropout
    Wx_plus_b = tf.nn.dropout(Wx_plus_b, keep_prob)
    if activation_function is None:
        outputs = Wx_plus_b
    else:
        outputs = activation_function(Wx_plus_b, )
    tf.summary.histogram(layer_name + '/outputs', outputs)
    return outputs

# define placeholder for inputs to network
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 64])  # 8x8
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

# add output layer
l1 = add_layer(xs, 64, 50, 'l1', activation_function=tf.nn.tanh)
prediction = add_layer(l1, 50, 10, 'l2', activation_function=tf.nn.softmax)

# the loss between prediction and real data
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(ys * tf.log(prediction),reduction_indices=[1]))  # loss
tf.summary.scalar('loss', cross_entropy)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.Session()
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
# summary writer goes in here
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logs/train", sess.graph)
test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logs/test", sess.graph)

# tf.initialize_all_variables() no long valid from
# 2017-03-02 if using tensorflow >= 0.12
if int((tf.__version__).split('.')[1]) < 12 and int((tf.__version__).split('.')[0]) < 1:
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
else:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess.run(init)
for i in range(500):
    # here to determine the keeping probability
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs: X_train, ys: y_train, keep_prob: 1})
    if i % 50 == 0:
        # record loss
        train_result = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={xs: X_train, ys: y_train, keep_prob: 1})
        test_result = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={xs: X_test, ys: y_test, keep_prob: 1})
        train_writer.add_summary(train_result, i)
test_writer.add_summary(test_result, i)
```

The right result is display scale in tensorboard.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot run the script more than once because otherwise you are creating nested graph**

For the first run, it will run OK without any errors. But when you run it more than once, nested computation graph will be created. You can view the behavior in tensorboard, after several runs, the computation graph will get bigger and bigger, and when you try to evaluate the bigger graph, extra placeholders simply don't get data fed to them and they will give error.

Here is the simple solution. Use `ft.reset_default_graph()` and put it before the place where you create the graph

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
# define placeholder for inputs to network
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='prob')
xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 64], name='x_input')  # 8x8
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='y_input')
...
```

some further reading [Remove nodes from graph or reset entire default graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765336/remove-nodes-from-graph-or-reset-entire-default-graph)